# oracle how to get column value from other table

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following tables with some columns:

> ```
>  foo
>   reportdate baar
>   01.04.16   1
>
>   baar_value
>   b_value from_date to_date
>   1       01.01.16   01.01.17
>   1       01.01.15   01.01.16
> ```

The logic of what I want is a little bit complex but I am trying to find a way to reference the reportdate from table foo in baar_value-where clause in the following query:

```
SELECT *
FROM foo
WHERE baar IS NOT NULL
AND NOT EXISTS
  (SELECT *
  FROM baar_value
  WHERE b_value = baar
  AND reportdate
  BETWEEN from_date AND to_date
  )
```

how check if foo.reportdate is between baar_value.from_date and baar_value_to_date?

Comment: What is recs_type_i930? Also, can you please post the expected result for that sample data?

Comment: I have changed this :)

Answer (score 0):

From your description maybe you simply need the following:

```
SELECT *
FROM foo
WHERE baar IS NOT NULL
AND NOT EXISTS
  (SELECT *
  FROM baar_value
  WHERE b_value = baar
    AND foo.reportdate BETWEEN from_date AND to_date
  )
```

**Test:**

```
SQL> create table foo(reportdate, baar) as
  2      select date '2016-04-01', 1 from dual;

Table created.

SQL> create table baar_value( b_value, from_date, to_date) as
  2      select 1, date '2016-01-01', date '2017-01-01' from dual union all
  3      select 1, date '2015-01-01', date '2016-01-01' from dual;

Table created.

SQL> SELECT *
  2  FROM foo
  3  WHERE baar IS NOT NULL
  4  AND NOT EXISTS
  5                (SELECT *
  6                FROM baar_value
  7                WHERE b_value = baar
  8                  AND foo.reportdate BETWEEN from_date AND to_date
  9                );

no rows selected
```

Comment: I tried this but I get the error ORA-00904: "foo"."reportdate" invalid identifier

Comment: Are you sure you got this error and the table structure is exactly as you posted? Just posted a test